# Which open source twitter clients properly support both twitter lists and read/unread?

Tags: software-recommendation, twitter

The client **must have this feature**: If I read a tweet in one list, that tweet must NOT display as unread in another list, or the main timeline. Choqok does not have this feature (yet).

Comment: Taking a closer look at your question, it seems like you don't understand how twitter wants you to use lists, since this isn't a feature that is on the website.

Comment: @RobinGreen - please can you regularly review this question - edit it with new information such as twitter clients you have tried.  If you consider it particularly important to you, you may wish to use a small bounty to encourage others to give you a clear answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with gwibber (default from Ubuntu). Then I began to use the Tweet Deck over Adobe Air till I find the famous "*green bird*" from OMGUbuntu. The Name of the "*green bird*" is **Polly** at it does have a nice integration with Unity and it does have multiple lists and also multiple accounts.
To install **Polly** with all the main features you will have to install the unstable version, but till now I had no problem at all and loving it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install polly
```

If you still not satisfied with Polly and want all the horse power you can get and using a proprietary program using **Tweet Deck** with **Adobe Air**

First you have to install **Adobe Air**, to do it so, download it from [here](http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin).

After you downloaded, you have to execute the commands:

```
chmod a+x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Now you have to install the Tweet Deck (*Note that Tweet Deck doesn't have a Desktop version any more, it's an old version*), to do it so download it from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25561731/TweetDeck_0_38.2.air).

After the download to install it just run the command:

```
chmod a+x TweetDeck_0_38.2.air
```

And Double click it for install

All credits to: [Polly](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/latest-update-to-twitter-app-polly-adds-real-time-updating/), [Tweet Deck](http://learnedstuffs.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/installing-tweetdeck-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to my answer my question, but it doesn't meet the requirements I stated in my question, at least not yet - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/polly/+bug/939646

Comment: So I guess that jrg already answered your question...If the tweet for one user that is in one list it will appear in another list if you have the same user in this list. There is no way to avoid it, since the lists are managed from Tweeter, and they made it to work it this way...it might be that the way that you use tweeter might be different as it supose to be used...but if you find some program that over-rides tweeter lists and does that, please let me know :) But if you are refering about that the program not showing the new tweets till you make it update it self, gwibber used to display it